# Is it possible this way? Letting computer to guess my number

Tags: python

I want pc to find the number in my mind with random function "every time"
so i tried something but not sure this is the correct direction and its not working as intended
how am i supposed to tell pc to guess higher than the previous guess
ps:code is not complete just wondering is it possible to do this way

```
def computer_guess():
myguess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))
pcguess = randint(1, 10)
feedback = ""
print(pcguess)
while myguess != pcguess:
    if myguess > pcguess:
        feedback = input("was i close?: ")
        return feedback, myguess
while feedback == "go higher":
    x = pcguess
    pcguess2 = randint(x, myguess)
    print(pcguess2)
```

Comment: The shown code is not indented correctly and you should describe in more detail how the code should work.

Comment: One of you isn't actually guessing. Do you want the computer to guess the number you *chose*, or do you want to guess the number the computer randomly picked?

Comment: I think you should only be telling the computer if its guess is right and if the right number is bigger. You might want standardized accepted input (like 'Y' or 'N'), and an input loop that reasks the question until it gets the right input. The `while feedback` loop is an infinite loop if entered as it is, it should only be an if-statement.

Comment: I want computer to guess the number i choose but with randint function. But randint function should filter the score by checking feedback above which i set it “go higher” for test purposes. gor example i typed 10 in input then computer guessed 3 wth randint function. So I typed “go higher” feedback input. Now pc should use randint between myguess and it’s previous guess. I hope i described it clearly

Comment: It's still not clear why the computer asks for "your" guess when it's the computer that is guessing. Maybe the right question would be "Enter the maximum value for guessing: "?

Comment: Oh i got it. It does not make any sence if pc asks my guess while its trying to guess mine .I ve realized when you said that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a few years ago and it's similar to what you're trying to do except this only asks for user input once then calls random and shrinks the range for the next guess until the computer guess is equal to the user input.

```py
import random
low = 0
high = 100
n = int(input(f'Chose a number between {low} and {high}:'))
count = 0
guess = random.randint(0,100)
lower_guess = low
upper_guess = high
while n != "guess":

    count +=1
    
    if guess < n:
        lower_guess = guess+1
        print(guess) 
        print("is low")
        next_guess = random.randint(lower_guess , upper_guess)
        guess = next_guess
        
    elif guess > n:
        upper_guess = guess-1
        print(guess) 
        print("is high")
        next_guess = random.randint(lower_guess , upper_guess)
        guess = next_guess
         
    else:
        print("it is " + str(guess) + '. I guessed it in ' + str(count) + ' attempts') 
        
        break
```

Comment: I would recommend using binary search instead of random guessing as there is a possibility that random guessing will guess everything but the number and could run forever